# Why isn't Javascript changing a variable with onChange?

Tags: javascript

So this is my code, I am wondering why changeUp isn't sending an alert to me or setting the variable value:

```
var selecteduname;
var xmlhttp;
function changeUp()
{
document.getElementById("useruname").onChange = function() {
    selecteduname = this.value;
    alert(selecteduname);
updateAdduser();
}


function loadXMLDoc()
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
}

function updateAdduser()
{loadXMLDoc();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var json = xmlhttp.responseText;
    var fields = JSON.parse(json);
    Object.keys(fields).forEach(function (name) {
  var input = document.getElementsByName(name);
  input.value = fields[name];
});
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajaxuseradd.psp?uname="+selecteduname, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

and

```
<form action="adduser.psp" method="get">
<fieldset>
    <label for="uname">Username:</label>
    <select name="uname" id="useruname" onChange="changeUp();">
<%
Blah blah blah Python Code to generate option values
%>


<%= options %> //More Python code, this actually puts them into the select box

</select>

</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Probably because the property's name is `onchange` not `onChange` (might still be more wrong with your code though).

Comment: Your code missing a few things... http://www.jshint.com/reports/61002

Comment: One quick thing for sure: You're missing a closing } at least, to end your loadXMLDoc method

Comment: @Itay Moav - Every modern browser supports this method of registering events. Yes, even IE7. Heck, even IE6. [Check it out](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html)

Comment: I think the closing } was the problem! Thanks! I need to start using an actual IDE for this.

EDIT: Nope, not quite. Got it to give me an alert, but not fill the fields. Argh.

Answer (score 1):

As commented above, the property name is "onchange", not "onChange". Javascript is case-sensitive, so those two are definitely different.

Also, the code you posted looks like it's missing a `}` somewhere. As it is, everything's inside the `changeUp` function. Which, coincidentally, never closes before that ending script tag.

However, there's something else going on here. This line in your markup:

```
<select name="uname" id="useruname" onChange="changeUp();">
```

Gets completely wiped out by this line in your code:

```
document.getElementById("useruname").onChange = function() {
```

Here's how I'd fix it up. First, the javascript:

```
function createAjax() {
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}


function updateAddUser(username) {
    var ajax = createAjax();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            var json = ajax.responseText;
            var fields = JSON.parse(json);
            Object.keys(fields).forEach(function (name) {
                var input = document.getElementsByName(name);
                input.value = fields[name];
            });
        }
    }
    ajax.open("GET", "ajaxuseradd.psp?uname=" + username, true);
    ajax.send();
}
```

Then you can just change the HTML `select` tag to:

```
<select name="uname" id="useruname" onchange="updateAddUser(this.value)">
```

Having said all that, I would strongly urge you try something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com). It would make the javascript code as trivial as:

```
$('#username').change(function(){
    $.get('ajaxuseradd.php', {uname:$(this).val()}, function(data, status, xhr) {
        $.each(data, function(key,value) {
            $('#'+key).val(value);
        });
    }, 'json');
});
```

Yeah, that's really terse, I know. More expressively, it could be written like this:

```
$('#username').change(function() {
    var userName = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'ajaxuseradd.php',
        data: {
            uname: userName
        },
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                $('#' + key).val(value);
            });
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    })
});
```

Comment: I have been considering using jQuery, but everyone who I talk to about it is very anti-jQuery, and says that learning "actual Javascript" is better.

Comment: "Everyone" is a very general term. Just do a quick google search, and you'll see that the people you are talking to are misinformed. jQuery has even been adopted by Microsoft as the official client-side javascript library for ASP.net. I've been programming in Javascript since '97, and jQuery is the best thing that's ever happened to it.

Comment: Ok, well, it seems easier, and more intuitive. Should I learn much more Javascript before learning it, or should I dive right in now?

Comment: It's a good idea to learn the underlying technology that jQuery is built on, so that you don't get caught unawares. But there's no reason you can't learn both jQuery and basic javascript at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a brace. Try running jslint on your code.

Secondly, You are trying to assign a function to the onChange event inside the method changeUp. Whereas changeUp is again the same method invoked in the first place. May be causing recursion.

Thanks,
RR