# Get selected value in dropdown menu populated by mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am making a form for the user to select year, make, and model of their vehicle. I am populating these fields with data from mysql. So far i can populate the year drop down menu without a problem but now I need to make a variable with the year the user selects and use it for my next query to revive the make. I have found different ways of doing this but none of which are populating their data from a database. I am trying to make a function in javascript and call it when the user changes the drop down field but for some reason it is not working.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javasccript">

        function run() {
            document.getElementById("userYear").innerHTML = 
            document.getElementById("year").value;
        }

</script>



<select id ="year" onChange="run()">
<option value ='Year'>Year</option>

<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response)) {
       echo "<option value='".$row['year']."'>".$row['year']."</option>";
} ?>

</select> 

<p>Your year is: </p><p id="userYear"></p> <!-- just for testing -->
```

Comment: You need to use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for this.

Comment: The main issue is that onchange is case sensitive for Javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000694/why-isnt-javascript-changing-a-variable-with-onchange  I submitted this as an answer but apparently it's trivial....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks *almost* correct and should work even if far from perfect. This is working example.

```js
      //typo javasccript
     //language="javascript" is obsolete
        function run(element) {
            document.getElementById("userYear").innerHTML = element.value;
           // document.getElementById("year").value;
        }
```

```html
<select id ="year" onchange="run(this)"><!--send element directly to the function -->
<option value ='Year'>Year</option>
<!--suppose php works fine and populates the list-->
<option value="2001">2001</option>
<option value="2002">2002</option>
<option value="2003">2003</option>
<option value="2004">2004</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option>
</select> 

<p>Your year is: </p><p id="userYear"></p> <!-- just for testing -->
```

Comment: the exact same thing given in my answer with a bit different code, i am astonished why that not worked for OP? as it worked in the example also

Comment: @AlivetoDie we answer simultaneously. I think the problem was with typo `text/javasccript`